# Firebase Storage.Objects.Create Error in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-storage

I have the following code below to upload A file to firebase from NodeJS

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("../service_account.json");
const Strings = require('../lang/strings');
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    storageBucket: `${Strings.DEFAULT_BUCKET_NAME}.appspot.com`
});
module.exports = {
    firebase: admin
};
```

Now I imported the above to the below file:

```
 const firebase = require("./firebase").firebase;

                 firebase.storage().bucket(bucketName).upload(uploadPath, {
                    gzip: true,
                    metadata: {
                        cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
                    },
                }).then((response) => {
                    console.log("Uploaded to Firebase with response=" + JSON.stringify(response));
                    fs.unlink(uploadPath, (err, data) => {

                    });
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log("Firebase Upload Error=" + error);
                    fs.unlink(uploadPath, (err, data) => {

                    });
                });
```

But after the upload I am getting the below error:

> Firebase Upload Error=Error: firebase-adminsdk-eveve@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object.

How can I resolve this. I wanted to simply store my files on Firebase Storage. I do not want to interface with Google Cloud Storage. I want to interface with strictly the Firebase Dashboard.

Comment: What roles do you have for your Service Account? What kind of access control you have for your bucket?

Comment: Analyzing your code, I can see you are importing Firebase Library to get the bucket, could you please explain why?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Firebase Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start#use_a_default_bucket), you can use **Admin Cloud Storage API** and to upload a file, your code will look as following:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const serviceAccount = require("../service_account.json");

const Strings = require('../lang/strings');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    storageBucket: `${Strings.DEFAULT_BUCKET_NAME}.appspot.com`
});

var bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

var filename = "PATH.png"

async function uploadFile() {

  const metadata = {
    metadata: {
    cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
  };

  // Uploads a local file to the bucket
  await bucket.upload(filename, {
    // Support for HTTP requests made with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`
    gzip: true,
    metadata: metadata,
  });

console.log(`${filename} uploaded.`);
```

However I can see that you are trying to upload a file to Firebase Cloud Storage from a [Firebase Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions#download_transform_and_upload_a_file). Please try the following:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp()

exports.uploadFile = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(bucketname);
  bucket.upload(tempFilePath, {
    // By setting the option `destination`, you can change the name of the
    // object you are uploading to a bucket.
    destination: destination,
    metadata: {
      cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
    },
  });

});
```